# Convert a dataframe with two columns to a Panda Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with two columns

`data = train[['Age', "Pclass"]]`

```
    Age Pclass
0   22.0    3
1   38.0    1
2   26.0    3
3   35.0    1
4   35.0    3
... ... ...
886 27.0    2
887 19.0    1
888 24.0    3
889 26.0    1
890 32.0    3
```

And I want a Pandas Series which looks like that:

```
Age       22.0
Pclass     3.0
Name: 0, dtype: float64
Age       38.0
Pclass     1.0
Name: 1, dtype: float64
Age       26.0
Pclass     3.0
Name: 2, dtype: float64
Age       35.0
Pclass     1.0
Name: 3, dtype: float64
Age       35.0
Pclass     3.0
...
```

How can I achieve this?

I tried many approaches

1. `series = data.iloc[0]`

But I get only the first result

```
Age       22.0
Pclass     3.0
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

2. `series = data.iloc[:]`

But I get a DataFrame again

3. `series = pd.Series(data['Age'], data['Pclass'])`

This is also not correct, because I get this result:

```
Pclass
3    35.0
1    38.0
3    35.0
1    38.0
3    35.0
     ... 
2    26.0
1    38.0
3    35.0
1    38.0
3    35.0
Name: Age, Length: 891, dtype: float64
```

Any other suggestions?

So I want to have this output when I compute `series[0]` which gives me back the ages and `series[1]` all Pclasses

```
38.0
26.0
35.0
...
```

Comment: Try `pd.Series([s for _, s in data.iterrows()])`?

Comment: Thanks but not exactly what I want. My goal is I want that the Series just have 2 index (0 and 1). Basically `series[0]` should give back all ages and `series[1]` the pclasses

Comment: Why not just use `data.transpose()` and get a dataframe with 2 rows, after all a dataframe is just a series of series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
series = []
for i in range(len(data)):
    series.append(data.iloc[i])
```

OUTPUT:

```
Age       22
Pclass     1

Name: 0, dtype: int64
Age       48
Pclass     2
Name: 1, dtype: int64
Age       12
Pclass     3
Name: 2, dtype: int64
Age       45
Pclass     1
Name: 3, dtype: int64
```

If you want output when you compute `series[0]` which gives you back the ages and `series[1]` all Pclasses, you can use `data['Age']` to give back all ages and `data['Pclass']` to give back all Pclass

Comment: Thank you! How can I save that to a variable instead printing out?

Comment: Check the edited answer

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
s = df.stack().droplevel(0)
print(s)
print(type(s))
```

OUTPUT:

```
Age       22.0
Pclass     3.0
Age       38.0
Pclass     1.0
Age       26.0
Pclass     3.0
Age       35.0
Pclass     1.0
Age       35.0
Pclass     3.0
dtype: float64
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

As per discussion in comments:

```
s = pd.Series(list(df.T.to_numpy()))
print(s)
print(type(s))
```

OUTPUT:

```
0    [22.0, 38.0, 26.0, 35.0, 35.0]
1         [3.0, 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 3.0]
dtype: object
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Comment: Thanks but not exactly what I want. My goal is I want that the Series just have 2 index (0 and 1). Basically `series[0]` should give back all ages and `series[1]` the pclasses. But here if I run `series[0]` I get 22.0 and `series[1]` I get 3.0 etc

Comment: Check the edited answer